# How to properly deal with date objects in JSON and HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Dates are driving me nuts.

I have a form that generates an object on submission:

```
formContents.date is "2011-02-25"

var dateObject = new Date(formContents.date);
```

So now dateObject is a JS object (Wed Feb 25 2011 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT))

When I send this over as JSON to my server and then retrieve it again the response that I get back is now a string.

```
"Wed Feb 25 2011 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)"
```

If I plug this string directly into HighCharts it doesn't work - HighCharts seems to require that all dates be in the form:

```
Date.UTC(2011, 02, 25)
```

Is JSON not able to send JS objects or something? How do I make sure that my response is

```
Date.UTC(2011, 02, 25)
```

So that HighCharts can understand it?

Comment: Generally highcharts require timestamps, Date.UTC() allows return it but not required. So check if you can return dates as timestmap in your backend

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm a little rough for these matters, so my "flinstone" solution will be to tranform the string:

```
a = "Wed Feb 25 2011 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)";
b = a.split(" ");
c = {
    Jan: 01, Feb: 02, Mar: 03, Abr: 03, May: 05, Jun: 06, 
    Jul: 07, Aug: 08, Sep: 09, Oct: 10, Nov: 11, Dec: 12
};

year = b[3];
month = c[b[1]];
day = b[2];

date = [year, month, day];
```

Comment: Thanks! Haha, what I ended up doing was going to Moment.js instead. Moment does all of this stuff for you.